# Why would you create a label target of type void with no name?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees, linq-expressions

There is a specific overload in the `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` class like so:

```
public static LabelTarget Label();
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268150%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says, *"Creates a `LabelTarget` representing a label with void type and no name."*

What does that even mean? Why would you ever create a label target of type void with no name?

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268150%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it works just as a label to no expression:

> ```
> // A label expression of the void type that is the target for Expression.Return().
> LabelTarget returnTarget = Expression.Label();
>
> // This block contains a GotoExpression that represents a return statement with no value. 
> // It transfers execution to a label expression that is initialized with the same LabelTarget as the GotoExpression. 
> // The types of the GotoExpression, label expression, and LabelTarget must match.
> BlockExpression blockExpr =
>     Expression.Block(
>        Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }), Expression.Constant("Return")),
>        Expression.Return(returnTarget),
>        Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }), Expression.Constant("Other Work")),
>        Expression.Label(returnTarget)
>    );
> ```

Here, a label is created and then marked at the end of the expression block. If it were created with a type, it would have to be assigned an expression during the second call to *Label*. Thus, as the second label doesn't have an expression assigned, the type has to be void.

As for the name, names of labels aren't compiled, so it's just for your convenience to be able to omit a name when you don't need one.